# Is `using namespace std::placeholders;` non-conformant?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

From § 2.10.3.2:

> Each identifier that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.

With that in mind, is this program standard conformant?  As it makes `_1` etc available from the global namespace?  Or is it OK because `std::placeholders` is considered "implementation"?  Or is it OK because `_1` isn't actually in the global namespace?  Something else?

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
int main(){}
```

Comment: As far as I understand it, it being reserved means that any "_1" in the global namespace must come from "the implementation", and the standard library is part of "the implementation".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the program is fine. Strictly speaking, a using-directive does not put any names into a namespace - it makes the names reachable by name lookup, but does not actually make them members of the namespace enclosing the using-directive.

Quoting C++11, 7.3.4:

> 2 A *using-directive* specifies that the names in the nominated namespace can be used in the scope in which the
>   *using-directive* appears after the *using-directive.* During unqualified name lookup (3.4.1), the names appear
>   as if they were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace which contains both the *using-directive* and the
>   nominated namespace. [ *Note:* In this context, “contains” means “contains directly or indirectly”. *—end
>   note* ]
>
> 3 A *using-directive* does not add any members to the declarative region in which it appears. ...

Notice the language "can be used," "as if they were declared" etc. No mention of actually making a name member of a different namespace.

As for access through a qualified name, 3.4.3.2 (Qualified name lookup for namespaces) says:

> 2 For a namespace `X` and name `m`, the namespace-qualified lookup set *S(X,m)* is defined as follows: Let
>   *S'(X,m)* be the set of all declarations of `m` in `X` and the inline namespace set of `X` (7.3.1). If *S'(X,m)* is not
>   empty, *S(X,m)* is *S'(X,m);* otherwise, *S(X,m)* is the union of *S(N<sub>i</sub>,m)* for all namespaces *N<sub>i</sub>* nominated
>   by *using-directives* in `X` and its inline namespace set.

I.e., separate rules for using-directives as well.

I would conclude from this that a using-directive does not make any names members of a namespace, and thus the `_` global namespace rules is not triggered and no Undefined Behaviour occurs.

Comment: That is pretty much what I initially answered as well, except I posted a program that I expected to fail, but which didn't fail. Your quote explains how unqualified name lookup will succeed, but qualified name lookup also succeeds. There's a bit more to it than what's in your answer. I'm trying to find the rest of the relevant bits of the standard too.

Comment: But if I'm a compiler writer, and I use `_1` for some reason as part of my implementation and put that in the global namespace, as allowed(?), will it be shadowed by `using namespace std;`?  If so, could that break my implementation?

Comment: @hvd I was in the process of addressing qualified lookup as well, now posted.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity As a responsible compiler writer, you should always fully qualify everything if any confusion is possible. This means you'd always write `::_1` when you meant your implementation-specific `_1` symbol, and as per 3.4.3.2/2, finding an actual member of the qualifying namespace disables using-directive lookup. So you'd be fine.

Comment: And that's exactly the bit I got wrong in my sample program. `namespace N { void f() { } } using namespace N; int main() { ::f(); }` is valid and unambiguously calls `N::f`. `namespace N { void f() { } } using namespace N; void f() { } int main() { ::f(); }` is valid and the call to `::f` is still unambiguous, even though a call to `f()` would now be ambiguous.

Comment: @Angew I think including hvd's examples in your answer would be of great benefit to future readers.